# Sharepoint online how to get « copy link » url with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I’m trying to get the « copy link » url from sharing documents on my sharepoint online.

[image]

How can i get this parameter with powershell script?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Call CSOM method `CreateAnonymousLink` - link to [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/mt143091(v%3Doffice.15)).

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteUrl = $null
$siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"

$username = "admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = 'my awesome password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username,$password)

Connect-PnPOnline –Url $siteUrl –Credentials $credential

$ctx = $null
$ctx = Get-PnPContext  

$web = $null
$web = Get-PnPWeb 
Write-Host "Web: " $web.Url


$list = $null
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "Documents"
Write-host "List: " $list.Title

$item = Get-PnPListItem -List Documents -Id 18
$ctx.Load($item)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-host "Item: " $item.Id " // " $item["FileLeafRef"]
$itemUrl = $web.Url  + $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $item["FileLeafRef"]

$ctxClient = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctxClient.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$password)

$link = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]::CreateAnonymousLink($ctxClient,$itemUrl,$false)
$ctxClient.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host "Link (view): "$link.Value

$link2 = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]::CreateAnonymousLink($ctxClient,$itemUrl,$true)
$ctxClient.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host "Link (edit): "$link2.Value

$ctx = $null

Write-Host "End" -f Green -b DarkGreen
Write-host " "
Write-host " "
```

Answer (score 0):

Great post. I'd also like to add that at least for what I'm doing, there's no need to create a new ClientContext object. I was able to use the context from the $web object by referencing its context as $web.Context.

```
$link = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]::CreateAnonymousLink($web.Context,$itemUrl,$false)
```